# How does SSR on NextJS really works?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I've been using NextJS for a while, but don't fully get how its SSR process really works.

I've put a `console.log` inside some components `return` method, and I see that those are executed on the client side. Shouldn't these be displayed on the server's console instead because SSR is being used?

Also, when I try to `console.log` the `window` object, NextJS throws an error saying that `window` is not defined. That left me more confused, because according to my previous test, `console.log` is running on the client side, but according to this error, it is running on the server.

Comment: You haven't selected answers for any of your previous questions. Be sure to go through past questions and click the empty checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most, to help others find it and to give people fake internet points.

Comment: @Raul, time to select an answer please. These are great response that deserve your attention.

Answer (score 8):

If you've set up React components to render on the server (which you should for non static sites), when code executes on the server in NodeJS, there is no window object. That only exists in the browser. You need to account for that in SSR components.

There are features of Next to control when components are available to the client or server only, like [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

In the end, on the server, Next is mostly doing [renderToString](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring), and serving the HTML from the server, no different than any other webserver serving HTML.

Once in the client, React "hydrates" the rendered DOM, as in it re-runs React over the HTML created by the server. It doesn't change the DOM, but it does add things like interactivity, click handlers, etc, that you've defined for your app.

Comment: But when a navigation is performed, NextJS explains that it fetches the page data using `getServerSideProps`. That will return a JSON, which will be used to re-render the page. But this re-render is done client side, not server side. So, it doesn't seem to be any SSR involved in this part.

Comment: But how does Nextjs manage dynamic components having state which need to re-render on state change, given that an SSR component is sent as just html?

Answer (score 1):

Server side nextjs generates .js in your .next directory if it is `GetServerSideProps`. If it is ISR (GetStaticProps + revalidate), then it generates .html, .json, and .js files in the .next directory for that page (or those pages if dynamic). If using `GetStaticProps` sans revalidate, it generates .html and .json in the .next directory. If using no server side rendering method (e.g., `GetStaticProps` or `GetServerSideProps`) then it only generates .html at build time (automatic static optimization).

There is more to it, but this is what I've noticed from inspecting the contents of the output pages in the `.next` directory